# Making apache server live in CentOS? (Linux Alternative for "Put Online" in WAMP)

Tags: apache

Prologue:
I would like to make my site live from my PC(Just for some testing).
In Windows, I just click on the WAMP icon in my tray and it gives me an option to "Put Online", meaning anyone on the internet can access the site if I give them the link(with my ip in it)

Current Situation:
I have switched to CentOS and can't find an option to make it online. I thought that there will be a switch in httpd.exe like
    /etc/init.d/httpd restart
But I cant find proper answer with google. Help me out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One question, local your server work?

If so take a look at [Small overview for iptables and Port 80](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-rhel-linux-open-port-using-iptables/)

Answer (score 0):

First of all make sure that the following is given:

I) In your httpd.conf look for:

> #Listen 12.34.56.78:80 
>       Listen 80

Make sure that Listen 80 is active (or the Port you want to use for)

II) Check your IPTABLES or your Firewall if the Port 80 is free to connect

Comment: The httpd.conf file is the same. 80 is active.
Where do I check and alter IPTABLES?
When I open my firewall configuration, it just closes. Probably a problem with the application. Is there any other way to modify the port permissions?

Answer (score 0):

You have to be a super user to accomplish it.

Open flle /etc/sysconfig/iptables:

```
vi /etc/sysconfig/iptables
```

This is the standard procedure
Append the following line and save

```
-A RH-Firewall-1-INPUT -m state --state NEW -m tcp -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
```

However this did not work for me so I deleted the lines which had "REJECT" in it and it worked

Do not forget to restart iptables service

```
service iptables restart
```

Thanks to donald123